# View not giving the desired output

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h2>This is the template</h2>
        {{ count }} items
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var MyNamespace = {};

        $(document).ready(function () {

            MyNamespace.Recipe = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: "li",
                render: function () {
                    return this.$el.text("Chicken Chilly");
                }
            })


            MyNamespace.MyTagView = Backbone.View.extend({

                initialize: function () {
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function () {
                    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html());
                    this.$el.html(template);
                    return this;
                },
                count: 4
            });
            var View = new MyNamespace.MyTagView();
            $("#content").html(View.el);
        });


    </script>
```

I get the output as 0 items , instead of 4 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
template: template('entry-template'),
```

you are generating html of your compiled template and `'entry-template'` context object (it's not an id, it's value object to your template). After generating that html you assign it to `template` property of `MyNamespace.MyTagView`

Later, in the `render` method, you are calling this template property (which is html) as it was a function:

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this));
```

but it is not a function, but a property containing generated html.

You should assign template like this:

```
template: template,
```